# make a request to an external api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

i am learning node js and i have a problem. basically I'm trying to create an api route that will make a call to an external api

but when I do a test with postman, I get the error "Cannot GET /api/books". has anyone have an idea?

here is my function. (for security reasons I did not add my APIkey in the post

```js
const pool = require("../db");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');



exports.getOneBooksbyName = (req, res, next) => {
    const   title = req.params;
    const APIKey = "";

    fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" +title+ "&key="+APIKey)
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.json();
        res.status(200).json(data); 

    }
    )
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).json({message:'error'})
    })
    

};
```

and then my route

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {getOneBooksbyName} = require('../controllers/books');

router.get('/?title', getOneBooksbyName);

module.exports = router;
```

and finally my app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const pool = require("./db.js")
const UserRoutes = require("./routes/user.js");
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const BookRoutes = require("./routes/book.js");


app.use(express.json()); //pour gerer les requetes POST

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.use((req,res,next)=>{// POUR CONTOUNER LA SECURITE CORS
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
});



app.use('/api/users' , UserRoutes);
app.use('/api/books' , BookRoutes);


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use java script and jquery to achieve this

Javascript function using jquery ajax to call API via URL and return result

```
function api_fetch(url) {
    var result = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(`response from fetch ${response}`)
            result =  response
        },
        error: function (error)
        {
            console.log(`response from fetch ${error}`)
            result = error
        }
    })

    return result
}
```

I personally created a Django API, and I need to check if there is a record for a number in a database, so I implemented another js function to call the API

```
function check_number(number) {
    let get = api_fetch(`/api/verifnum/${number}`)
    console.log(`check number fetch ${get}`)
}
```

when I console log check number it gives me desired result

```
check_number('number') // returns number of record if exist or 0
```